# Sum Multiple Date Ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

requirement to look forward 6 months and sum the demand for each product per month for each manufacture looking 6 months ahead. I have done a little work to make tables and column names more understandable.

I need to be able to sum some quantities across multiple date ranges. below is where I got myself to but has the massive issue of sum-ing the whole lot in every month it see's a product, rather than just the months demand.

```
@Manufacturer VARCHAR(10)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

            SELECT 
                CASE
                WHEN o.CLOSEDATE Between GETDATE() And DateAdd(MONTH,+6,GETDATE()) AND m.CODE = @Manufacturer THEN p.PRODUCTCODE
            END AS 'Product',   
                CASE
                WHEN o.CLOSEDATE Between GETDATE() And DateAdd(MONTH,+1,GETDATE()) AND m.CODE = @Manufacturer THEN SUM(ql.QUANTITY)
            END AS 'Month 1 Quantity',
                CASE
                WHEN o.CLOSEDATE Between DateAdd(MONTH,+1,GETDATE()) And DateAdd(MONTH,+2,GETDATE()) AND m.CODE = @Manufacturer THEN SUM(ql.QUANTITY)
            END AS 'Month 2 Quantity',
                CASE
                WHEN o.CLOSEDATE Between DateAdd(MONTH,+2,GETDATE()) And DateAdd(MONTH,+3,GETDATE()) AND m.CODE = @Manufacturer THEN SUM(ql.QUANTITY)
            END AS 'Month 3 Quantity',
                CASE
                WHEN o.CLOSEDATE Between DateAdd(MONTH,+3,GETDATE()) And DateAdd(MONTH,+4,GETDATE()) AND m.CODE = @Manufacturer THEN SUM(ql.QUANTITY)
            END AS 'Month 4 Quantity',
                CASE
                WHEN o.CLOSEDATE Between DateAdd(MONTH,+4,GETDATE()) And DateAdd(MONTH,+5,GETDATE()) AND m.CODE = @Manufacturer THEN SUM(ql.QUANTITY)
            END AS 'Month 5 Quantity',
                CASE
                WHEN o.CLOSEDATE Between DateAdd(MONTH,+5,GETDATE()) And DateAdd(MONTH,+6,GETDATE()) AND m.CODE = @Manufacturer THEN SUM(ql.QUANTITY)
            END AS 'Month 6 Quantity'
            
            FROM OPPORTUNITY AS o
            JOIN CUSTOMEROPPORTUNITY AS co (NOLOCK)
            on co.ID = o.ID
            JOIN CUSTOMER AS c (NOLOCK)
            on co.CUSTOMER = c.ID
            JOIN ENTITYRELATIONSHIP AS er (NOLOCK)
            on er.C_ENTITY1 = o.ID
            JOIN QUOTATION AS sq (NOLOCK)
            on er.ENTITY2 = sq.ID
            JOIN SALESQUOTATIONLINE AS ql (NOLOCK)
            on ql.OWNER = sq.ID
            JOIN PRODUCT AS p (NOLOCK)
            on p.ID = ql.PRODUCT
            JOIN MANUFACTURER AS m (NOLOCK)
            on m.ID = p.MANUFACTURER
            JOIN OPPORTUNITYSOURCE AS os (NOLOCK)
            on o.OPPORTUNITYSOURCE = os.ID
            JOIN OPPORTUNITYSTATUS AS wf (NOLOCK)
            on o.WORKFLOWSTATUS = wf.ID
            WHERE m.CODE = @Manufacturer AND wf.CODE != 'LOST' AND o.CLOSEDATE Between GETDATE() And DateAdd(MONTH,+12,GETDATE())
            GROUP BY p.PRODUCTCODE, o.CLOSEDATE, m.CODE
END
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're spamming the `NOLOCK` hint? Do you understand what it's doing? If you do "need" (you don't) to use it against every table (though `OPPORTUNITY` oddly doesn't), why are you not change the isolation level of the transaction instead (and use a different hint against `OPPORTUNITY`)? I suggest having a read of [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results

Comment: Also, good use of whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. The lack of indetation makes your code quite difficult to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues here:

- Put the `CASE` *inside* the `SUM`, so that you are conditionally aggregating.
- Remove `CLOSEDATE` from the `GROUP BY`
- You probably want to truncate to the beginning of the day, you can do this using `CAST as date`
- A check on `m.CODE = @Manufacturer` is not necessary, you are doing it in the `WHERE` anyway.
- Use date ranges `>= AND <` rather than `BETWEEN`. See [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).
- Use `[]` to quote column names, not `''`.
- Do NOT use `NOLOCK`, it has serious data integrity implications, and probably doesn't do what you think it does. If you need to avoid blocking then use `SNAPSHOT`.

```
SELECT 
  p.PRODUCTCODE AS Product,
  SUM(CASE WHEN o.CLOSEDATE >=                   CAST(GETDATE() AS date)  AND o.CLOSEDATE < CAST(DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE()) AS date) THEN ql.QUANTITY END) AS [Month 1 Quantity],
  SUM(CASE WHEN o.CLOSEDATE >= DATEADD(month, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) AND o.CLOSEDATE < CAST(DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE()) AS date) THEN ql.QUANTITY END) AS [Month 2 Quantity],
  SUM(CASE WHEN o.CLOSEDATE >= DATEADD(month, 2, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) AND o.CLOSEDATE < CAST(DATEADD(month, 3, GETDATE()) AS date) THEN ql.QUANTITY END) AS [Month 3 Quantity],
  SUM(CASE WHEN o.CLOSEDATE >= DATEADD(month, 3, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) AND o.CLOSEDATE < CAST(DATEADD(month, 4, GETDATE()) AS date) THEN ql.QUANTITY END) AS [Month 4 Quantity],
  SUM(CASE WHEN o.CLOSEDATE >= DATEADD(month, 4, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) AND o.CLOSEDATE < CAST(DATEADD(month, 5, GETDATE()) AS date) THEN ql.QUANTITY END) AS [Month 5 Quantity],
  SUM(CASE WHEN o.CLOSEDATE >= DATEADD(month, 5, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) AND o.CLOSEDATE < CAST(DATEADD(month, 6, GETDATE()) AS date) THEN ql.QUANTITY END) AS [Month 6 Quantity]
FROM OPPORTUNITY AS o
JOIN CUSTOMEROPPORTUNITY AS co ON co.ID = o.ID
JOIN CUSTOMER AS c ON co.CUSTOMER = c.ID
JOIN ENTITYRELATIONSHIP AS er ON er.C_ENTITY1 = o.ID
JOIN QUOTATION AS sq ON er.ENTITY2 = sq.ID
JOIN SALESQUOTATIONLINE AS ql ON ql.OWNER = sq.ID
JOIN PRODUCT AS p ON p.ID = ql.PRODUCT
JOIN MANUFACTURER AS m ON m.ID = p.MANUFACTURER
JOIN OPPORTUNITYSOURCE AS os ON o.OPPORTUNITYSOURCE = os.ID
JOIN OPPORTUNITYSTATUS AS wf ON o.WORKFLOWSTATUS = wf.ID
WHERE m.CODE = @Manufacturer
  AND wf.CODE != 'LOST'
  AND o.CLOSEDATE >= CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
  AND o.CLOSEDATE < CAST(DATEADD(month, 12, GETDATE()) AS date)
GROUP BY
  p.PRODUCTCODE;
```

Comment: amazing. thank you.
do you have a link to anything explaining the issues with NOLOCK? as google is giving me lots of answers for what it does and how to use it but nothing explaining why not.

lots of little things for me to keep in mind

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/11/nolock-is-bad-and-you-probably-shouldnt-use-it/ and https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/using-nolock-heres-how-youll-get-the-wrong-query-results/ and https://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-uncommitted-isolation-level and https://blog.coeo.com/using-with-nolock-read-this. I'll put it this way: given that `NOLOCK` can cause rows to be returned multiple times, then you may get really strange results, especially with a complex join query such as this, Suppose a join such as `PRODUCT` doubled up, your entire resultset would double.

Comment: It simply doesn't make sense to use it in 99% of cases. If you are using it for performance then just use `TABLOCK` and get a single lock on the whole table. And if that sounds to you like it's going to block someone then you *really* have problems with `NOLOCK` as it means someone else is modifying rows at the same time. So in that case use `SNAPSHOT` to get a point-in-time (row-versioned) view of the table as as the start of the statement/transaction. The *only* time you would ever use `NOLOCK` is when diagnosing some blocking problems, or running DBA queries, neither of which are likely.